# Change Link Visibility -- Event Listener with mouseover and getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener, getelementsbyclassname

*I am relatively new to JavaScript.*

I've searched the internet over and found what people are calling solutions and correct scripts and fixes etc., but none of them seem to work for me so I'm clearly missing something. Been troubleshooting for hours now. Please help!

CSS: I have created a simple two-column div (out of 12, it's floated left). I have a CSS transition in place to pull it from 2% width to 15% width (nearly the full two columns) on hover.

HTML: I created a few test links in the div which I've hidden with a CSS class.

JS: I am trying to use JavaScript to make them visible when the mouse is over the div.

HTML:

```
<div id="linkpopout" class="col-2 popout">
  <a href="www.bing.com" class="menulinks">Bing</a>
  <a href="www.yahoo.com" class="menulinks">Yahoo</a>
  <a href="www.google.com" class="menulinks">Google</a>      
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}

.popout {
  background:lightblue;
  transition:width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function:ease-out;
  width:2%;
  height:300px;
  float:left;
}

.popout:hover {
  width:15%;
  height:300px;
}

.menulinks {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
var linkpop = document.getElementById("linkpopout");
var popoutlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("menulinks");
linkpop.addEventListener("mouseover", makeVisible);
function makeVisible() {
  popoutlinks.style.visibility="visible";
}
```

For what it's worth, I've also tried `document.getElementsByClassName(menulinks").style.visibility="visible";`
without any luck and I've tried accomplishing the same thing using opacity instead of visibility and that made no difference.

Thank you.

Comment: The getElementsByClassName returns an array-like list of elements with the required class. You need to then loop through the returned list of elements and apply the addEventListener function. You will also need to add a mouseout event call otherwise the elements wont hide themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to toggle the visibility of the links depending on whether the menu is showing or not. You can do it like this;

JS:

```
<script>
var linkpop = document.getElementById("linkpopout");
var popoutlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("menulinks");
linkpop.addEventListener("mouseover", makeVisible);
linkpop.addEventListener("mouseout", makeVisible);

function makeVisible() {
  for (let i = 0; i < popoutlinks.length; i++) {
    popoutlinks[i].classList.toggle("vis");
  }
}
</script>
```

The 'toggle' method of 'classList' which is bound to an element will add or remove the class from the element depending on its current state. If the class is there, it will remove it, otherwise, it will add it. Very useful for popout menus like this. We have to loop through all of the elements, in this case your `menulinks` and toggle the class per element.

Then have a class to toggle on or off. Default state is bound to the default class you want for the element.

CSS:

```
.menulinks { visibility:hidden; }
.vis { visibility:visible }
```

Comment: Worked on the first try and I actually understand why now. That's a handy method. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Josh I saw your other comment about wanting to learn more in terms of JS and interacting with the DOM. This is a very useful place for learning - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web

Comment: Thank you. I'll bookmark it. I did come across that a few times trying to figure this out, but never really stopped. I'll go through it more thoroughly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

No need for JavaScript.

```css
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}

.popout {
  background:lightblue;
  transition:width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function:ease-out;
  width:2%;
  height:300px;
  float:left;
}

.popout:hover {
  width:15%;
  height:300px;
}

.menulinks {
  visibility:hidden;
}

.popout:hover .menulinks {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkpopout" class="col-2 popout">
  <a href="www.bing.com" class="menulinks">Bing</a>
  <a href="www.yahoo.com" class="menulinks">Yahoo</a>
  <a href="www.google.com" class="menulinks">Google</a>      
</div>
```

Comment: Despite having an answer of my own using JS, I would agree this is the best solution.

Comment: This is very simple and is probably where I should have turned in the first place. I'm trying, specifically, to stretch myself with JavaScript and learn more about how it works with HTML and CSS, but oh my gosh is this a simple, effective solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You need to loop through the DOM elements:**

`getElementsByClassName`

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

```
function makeVisible() {
  popoutlinks.forEach(function(e) {
      e.style.visibility="visible";
  });   
}
```